# chrome extension how do I inject javascript code to the chrome setting pages "chrome://inspect/#device"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

==== background ====
Sorry for the bother.
I'm new to chrome extension development.
I found that I was unable to inject js code in chrome://inspec/#device (the chrome build-in page) by using tabs.executeScript.

My requirements is that, I'm trying to auto-catch the web-view network requests and responses. I finished this by created a devtools extension.

Meantime, I need to auto-detect the device list in the "chrome://inspect/#device" page, then inject the js code to click the "inspect" link to launch the devtools instead of manually clicked every time.

=== Issues ===
1. I tried add content scrips, add the "chrome://*/*" matches, not work.
2. I then tried add permissions of "chrome://*/*", not work either.

So, how do I inject javascript code to the chrome setting pages "chrome://inspect/#device"?

Best Regards,
Lucas Luo

Comment: Hi wOxxOm, thanks for the replay. I tried your steps, 1) when install extension, chrome told me `Invalid scheme for 'permissions[chrome://*/*]'`. 2) when running the ext, the parameter `state` in the callback function of `chrome.permissions.contains` is undefined, which means unable to get the `chrome://*/*`.

Comment: actually it's unable to get the `chrome://*/*` permission on my side, always false when using `permissions: {original: ["chrome://*/*"]`.

Comment: Changing a flag requires restarting the browser.

Comment: I've changed the flag, still return false.

Comment: also restarted browser.

Comment: thanks, restart computer, works now.

Comment: It means that the browser was running in background, so to exit it you should use the Exit command in the menu or terminate all `chrome` processes in a task manager.